# Extracting a part of the scipy sparse matrix

Tags: arrays, scipy, extract, sparse-matrix

In numpy, we can extract a part of the 2d array in the following way

```
arr = np.random.random((4,4))
arr_reduced = arr[0:2, 2:4]
```

Is there any similar way to get a part of scipy sparse matrix?

I know that there are ways to extract nonzero blocks from the array, but what if the desired array is not same as the blocks?

Comment: have you tried the same syntax?  result? error?  Ant thing in the docs?

Comment: Ohh, Thanks. The same syntax works for the sparse matrices as well. I should have checked that.

Comment: It does depend on the format.. It works well for computational friendly `csr`, but not for `coo`